# Add anchor tag to simple jQuery sideshow

Tags: jquery, anchor, slideshow

I am using one of [snook.ca](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) script for simple slideshow. Here it is in a nutshell:

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="banner1.jpg" width="645" height="307"/>
    <img src="banner2.jpg" width="645" height="307"/>
    <img src="banner3.jpg" width="645" height="307"/>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 4000);
});
</script>
```

Now I have tried to make these images clickable at while in slideshow. So my markup will be something like:

```
<div class="fadein">
    <a href="yahoo.com"><img src="banner1.jpg" bwidth="645" height="307"/></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="banner2.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
    <a href="live.com"><img src="banner3.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this functionality without making the script too complicated. **Please note** that `<img/>` tags are provided to me and I have no control over it.

Comment: The markup is like that, or you need the script to make the markup like that as well?

Comment: The markup is set, Just need to change the script to suit the markup.

Comment: Note: you have 'bwidth' instead of 'width' in the first img tag repeatedly, so I'd assume it's in your (test?) markup.

Comment: @DN: Yeah, something went wrong while copy pasting.. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from [CrazyJugglerDrummer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367846/add-anchor-tag-to-simple-jquery-sideshow/2367889#2367889)'s try, you'd want to hide and then cycle the `a`s, not the `img`s. Otherwise you'll be looking for `next('img')` where it doesn't exist.

**update** Seems like it's a mix of CSS and js. I have it working now, like so:

```
<div class="fadein">
  <a href="yahoo.com"><img src="banner1.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
  <a href="google.com"><img src="banner2.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
  <a href="live.com"><img src="banner3.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.fadein a:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein a:first-child').fadeOut().next('a').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 4000);
});
</script>
```

with CSS

```
.fadein { position:relative; width:645px; height:307px; }
.fadein a { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; text-decoration:none; }
img { border:0; display:block; }
```

You have to make sure your anchors and images are displayed block, and that the absolute position is set on your anchor. *Also* you need to further specify the `:first-child` so as not to fade the image.

**further update** Using 1.3.2 jQuery and XHTML Strict. Works in FF, IE6 - 8, Safari, Chrome, and Opera.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .fadein { position:relative; width:645px; height:307px; }
  .fadein a { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; text-decoration:none; }
  img { border:0; display:block; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fadein a:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){$('.fadein a:first-child').fadeOut().next('a').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 4000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fadein">
    <a href="yahoo.com"><img src="banner1.jpg" width="645" height="307" alt="1" /></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="banner2.jpg" width="645" height="307" alt="2" /></a>
    <a href="live.com"><img src="banner3.jpg" width="645" height="307" alt="3" /></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DN: I have tried that as well and for some reason the script won't work as it should. Like the fade effect is gone. It only switch the first image, and after a while the image disappears.

Comment: Updated. Working now for me. Let me know.

Comment: @DN: Nice, however the fade effect is not working. At least not in firefox!

Comment: @Mazzi That's what I'm testing in, and it was for me. It's rather quick, but it's there.

Comment: You can edit how fast the fade goes by editing .fadeIn and .fadeOut to something like .fadeIn("slow") or .fadeIn(5000).

Comment: For some reason it just doesn't like the effect! no matter what the parameter is!

Comment: That's very odd. I would actually try closing down your browser and reopening it. I just tested in FF3, IE8, and Chrome, and it works everywhere. Also, if it's changing *at all*, the effect is actually working. This might also be a content issue--what your images look like could make an effect more or less visible.

Comment: Nah, its still doesn't like it! Mine is basically identical to yours! The effect is not fast its just not there.. Here is mine:http://tinypaste.com/09504

Comment: That works, too. The only way I've been able to reproduce any problem is when I accidentally removed the </script> tag. Then it's just dead. Incidentally, there should be no 'name' attribute in the images (usually only used for <a>s in HTML and <input>s in HTML and XHTML).

Comment: Okay, so updated with the exact file as I have it. I can attest to it working, with effect, on every browser I have. I'd start looking at the differences between your full version and mine to sniff out any other problems. Possible issue: if you're running an HTML doctype instead of an XHTML one, you should nix the trailing slashes from the image tags.

Answer (score 1):

You want to [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the images with anchor tags? Where do the anchors come from? Assuming you will be placing them within an array:

```
var link = ['www.example.com', 'www.example.net'];
$("div.fadein > img").each(function(i) {
    var $anchor = $("<a></a>").attr("href", link[i]); // or $(this).attr("src") depending on what you mean
    $(this).wrap($anchor);
});
```

or have I completely misunderstood the question? If you just need them to be clickable can't you just assign a click handler to each one, i.e.:

```
$("div.fadein > img").click(function() {
   window.location.href = $(this).attr("src"); // assuming the href is the images source
});
```

or:

```
var link = ['www.example.com', 'www.example.net'];
$("div.fadein > img").each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        window.location.href = link[i];
    });
});
```

Note that the above examples assume that you have the same number of links as you do images, and that they are in the correct order.

Comment: You second example was closer to my solution. However for each image there is link url. How do I go with associating url links to each image? Perhaps an array?

Comment: I've thrown in a third example to address your comment. I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the HTML in 'fadein', change it to what you listed and it should work.

```
<div class="fadein">
    <a href="yahoo.com"><img src="banner1.jpg" bwidth="645" height="307"/></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="banner2.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
    <a href="live.com"><img src="banner3.jpg" width="645" height="307"/></a>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 4000);
});
</script>
```

You select and fade the first child, which is now the `<a>`. Even if you faded in the just the images, as long as they're inside `<a>`s the link will be followed.